# how can I get 1 workspace per solution?

Tags: visual-studio

i am using vs.net with tfs. I have 1 workspace at the moment for 1 solution. I just did a get latest from another solution but now it already checks stuff out in the same workspace? how can I get one workspace for each solution so every things stays seperate?

Answer (score 2):

With opened 'Source Control Explorer' navigate in VS to

> 'File' > 'Source Control' > 'Workspaces...'

From there you can generate any number of workspaces, containing any number of source control paths.
Once you have generated your workspaces you toggle from one to another from within 'Source Control Explorer'

Answer (score 1):

Inside a workspace you can create several mappings. A mapping links a directory in your source control to a path on your local drive. You can map *$\Team Project\trunk* to *c:\temp* and *$\Team Project\Component\Subcomponent\trunk* to *c:\somepath\someotherpath*.

Now you can call Get Latest. This can be done on several levels:

1. Get Latest on $\
2. Get Latest on $\Team Project\
3. Get Latest on $\Team Project\trunk\

The first one updates all your local mappings because the Get Latest has been done on the topmost level of your source control.

The second call will also update both mappings, because both mappings are below *$\Team Project*.

The third call will only update your first mapping because it's the only mapping below this path.

So the conclusion is: You do not have to separate your Team Project mappings into several workspaces. You just have to take care of the level you call Get Latest on.